# Cambiar fecha o zona horaria en JBOSS 5.1

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jboss-as-7, jboss-5.x

Estoy intentando replicar un error que surgió en producción al desplegar un proyecto.
Hay un objeto de tipo Date que viene desde la BD con (aparentemente) un formato incorrecto.
Para replicar el error necesito cambiar la hora de mi JBoss AS 5.1.
Estoy buscando desde el server en mi IDE y en la carpeta del Jboss alguna opción o archivo de configuración (respectivamente) para hacerlo pero no encuentro nada.

Gracias de antemano.

PD: he comprobado que JBoss toma la hora de mi pc al momento de iniciar el servidor localmente, por lo que modificar la hora manualmente y después iniciar el servidor me sirvió momentáneamente.

PD2: también me serviría cambiar la zona horaria, investigando encontré indicaciones para realizar esto pero en JBoss 7.1 y como aclaré antes el mio es el 5.1.

Comment: Diga _desplegar_, no _deployar_. Ya en serio, bienvenidx a SOes. En dónde exactamente ves que la hora "no está bien"? Podría ser cosa del OS y no del servidor web, ¿no? Siéntete libre de [edit] la pregunta y añadir toda la info y la respuesta a estas preguntas

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: Buenas tarde mi estimado, eso debe de ser por que tu servidor tienes unas hora de retraso. mira por alli que va el lio.